# ExtJS: Editing an entire grid and saving it all at once

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a requirement to produce a grid where all the rows are in edit mode and values for each row can be saved at once by a single click of a Save button. Is this possible? If so, what's the best way of doing this? Is it a good idea to use ExtJs' grid for this requirement? By looking at Ext Js' examples, the framework developers seem to highly encourage grids to be edited at one row or cell at a time instead of the entire table.

I would also like to note that paging is not a requirement.

**Update:**
I'm using Ext JS 3.4.

Comment: Which Version of ExtJS do you want to use?

Comment: I'm using Ext JS v3.4

Comment: Is this Question still open ? Or you got answer some where else ?
You can achieve it by using "store.getModifiedRecords()" .

If Question is still open let me know will post a working code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Ok, this is just correct for Ext JS v. 4.x :)

What you could do is to set in the underlying Store the `autoSync: false`, so that it will not immediately write the changes to the server.

On your Save Button you just call `grid.getStore().sync()`

see: [API - Ext.data.Store.sync()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync)

Comment: Mario, He is using Ext JS v3.4, and this sync() is not present in 3.x I guess.

Answer (score 1):

May be below code helps :

```
/**
 *   This method is called on save button click by passing the grid object as a parameter
 */
saveGridModifiedRecords = function (yourGrid) {
    Ext.getCmp("yourGridId").body.mask('Saving Record Please Wait...');
    var modifiedRecords = yourGrid.getStore().getModifiedRecords();
    var CIxml = StringToXML("<Root/>");
    for (var i = 0; i < modifiedRecords.length; i++) {
        var fields = modifiedRecords[i]; // Gives you each edited record
        var cuurElem = CIxml.createElement("I");
        cuurElem.setAttribute("name", fields.get("name")); // Here name is the dataindex of a field
        cuurElem.setAttribute("category", fields.get("category")); // Here category is the dataindex of a field
        CIxml.documentElement.appendChild(cuurElem);
    }

    Use an AJAX call to send this xml with modified records to server.

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'yourWebServiceURL/parameter1/parametr2',
        method : 'POST',
        timeout : 120000,
        params : {
            'strIPXML' : CIxml.xml
        }, // We are passing xml as a string here by using .xml
        success : function (response) {
            // Extract response.resposeXML for a xml format of response else response.responseText for a string.
            Ext.getCmp("yourGridId").body.unmask();
            alert('In success');
        },
        failure : function (response) {
            alert('In Failure');
            if (Ext.getCmp("yourGridId")) {
                Ext.getCmp("yourGridId").body.unmask();
            }
        }
    });
}

function StringToXML(oString) {
 //code for IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
 var oXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); oXML.loadXML(oString);
 return oXML;
 }
 // code for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc. 
 else {
 return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(oString, "text/xml");
 }
}
```